# How to perform some action before webViewDidfinish method in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, wkwebview, completionhandler

I have an iframe which, I have loaded into webview. Before loading webview I have to perform some function to complete then it loads iframe content.

I have a function called loadhtmlString() and I will call loadFormView() in webViewDidFinish method.

But my issue is before completing the loadhtmlString() function webViewDidFinish method is called and iframe content is not loading.

How to wait for the complete function to finishing and then load the webViewDidFinish method?

```
  func loadHTMLStringImage(){

            let fileManager = FileManager.default
                  let documentsDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
                  guard let sourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html") else {
                      return
                  }

                  if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: sourcePath) {
                      let sourceUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: sourcePath)
                      try? fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("www").path,
                                                       withIntermediateDirectories: false,
                                                       attributes: nil)
                      let destination = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("www/index.html", isDirectory: false)
                      try? fileManager.copyItem(at: sourceUrl, to: destination)


                      if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destination.path) {
                          print("file copied")




                        let sou = destination.path
                        print("sou, s", sou)

                        let des = documentsDirectory.path
                        print("des sd", des)
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(sou, forKey: "destURL")
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(des, forKey: "sourceURL")
                        md5Val()

                        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
                          config.setValue(true, forKey: "allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs")


                      } else {

                          print("file copy failed")
                        self.view.removeLoading()
                      }
                  }



            webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

            webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "saveHandler")
            webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "openCamera")
            webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "completeForm")
            webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "handleFormState")
            webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "openImage")
            webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "tabForm")

}
```

webViewDidFinish method, I am calling another function:

```
   public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {


    loadFormView()
    print("Web View didFinish Loading");
    self.view.removeLoading()



   }
```

After completing loadHTMLStringImage() function, I want to call webViewDidFinish Method.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have updated my question with code, can you check it out